# SQL SERVER 2008

Tags: iis

I changed my domain name last week. So the administrator@domainname also changed.
Now i am not able to log on windows authentication mode in sql server. I want to change the windows authentication account to new administrator account. 
can anyone help me to sovw this issue.

Regards 
Suresh

Answer (score 1):

1. Log in to SQL Server using *SQL Server Authentication* (`sa` account).
2. Navigate to *Security* / *Logins*.
3. Add the new administrator account and assign it to appropriate server roles.

Comment: +1 Do you think "administrator@oldDomainName" would still work? Just in case OP doesn't know the `sa` pwd.

Comment: @Groo He cannot use the "administrator@oldDomainName" account to access SQL Server, because he cannot log in to Windows using this account.

Comment: Oh, right, I am talking nonsense, win authentication is just using existing user accounts.

Answer (score 1):

Start the server in single user mode & you'll be able to set up new accounts.  Lots of examples on this site and in TechNet/MSDN of how to work in single user mode.